# how to put <span> and <button> on the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

here is what it looks like:

[image]

and my html:

```
<div>
  <div class="dropdown col-md-6">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="width:150px;">warehouse</span>
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle "type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" style="display:inline;">
  select warehouse
  <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to put the warehouse and select warehouse on the same line,how to do it?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: maybe [Segmented buttons](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/#segmented-buttons) can help you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the surrounding div an input group (add the "input-group" class):

```
<div class="dropdown col-md-6 input-group">
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="dropdown col-md-6">
```

You might want to look at the Input Group / Input Group Add-On documentation:
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/

Comment: with this solution you can also remove the inline style of the span :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to also specify `display:inline` for the span to overwrite the `display: table-cell;` of the `.input-group-addon` class on it.

[See this bootply fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/3dA1J9Lcjf)

Answer (score 1):

(bad practice alert)

To make *exactly* what you ask, you can use this style

```
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="display:inline-block; width:auto;float:left;height:35px;line-height:21px;">warehouse</span>
```

Comment: If this a bad practice then don't give it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can also be like this.

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
  <span class="col-md-2 control-label">Metadata</span>
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example</button>
</div>
```